# Inconsistent tab indentation in command line Python

Tags: python, indentation

I am running Python 3.5.2 64-bit on Windows. When I type a class in the command prompt, manually indenting the code with tab, the first level indentation is equal to 4 characters, and the second level is for some reason 8 (I press tab twice, and get 4 + 8 characters). It looks like this:

```
    class Klass():
        def __init__(self):
                print('klass')
```

Auto indentation in Idle gives the same result. This inconsistency bothers me, can it be fixed?

Comment: Avoid using tabs. use spaces instead.

Comment: If you use the interactive interpreter, I strongly suggest you to use ipython: https://ipython.org/ `pip install ipython`. It will auto indent the code properly.

Comment: It occured to me that python command line as well as Idle compensate for the '>>> ' in the first line of compound (in this case) statements. As suggested, ipython's behavior is more consistent.